# ASP.NET Core MVC Dropdown box with single select

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to learn ASP .NET Core and I'm making a simple web app to track wins/losses in a video game I play. On one screen I'd like the user to select a character and a stage from two dropdown boxes which are populated with data from a SQL database. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the boxes to display as a single-select dropdown box. They will only appear as multi-select boxes with a scrollbar inside.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using for my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    Repository _repository = new Repository();

    public HomeController(IConfiguration config, DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.configuration = config;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult AddGame()
    {
        List<CharacterViewModel> characterList = new List<CharacterViewModel>();
        List<StageViewModel> stageList = new List<StageViewModel>();

        characterList = (from Name in _context.Characters select Name).ToList();
        characterList.Insert(0, new CharacterViewModel { CharacterID = 0, Name = "" });
        ViewData["characterList"] = characterList;
        ViewBag.characterList = characterList;


        stageList = (from Stage in _context.Stages select Stage).ToList();
        stageList.Insert(0, new StageViewModel { StageID = 0, Name = "" });
        ViewData["stageList"] = stageList;
        ViewBag.stageList = stageList;

        AddGameViewModel addGameViewModel = new AddGameViewModel();
        addGameViewModel.Characters = characterList;
        addGameViewModel.Stages = stageList;

        return View(addGameViewModel);
    }
}
```

For my character model (stage model is almost identical):

```
public class CharacterViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CharacterID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CharacterName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And finally my view:

```html
<form asp-controller="HomeController" asp-action="AddGame" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <p>Character</p>
            <select asp-for="Characters" id="characterSelect"
                    class="dropdown"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.CharacterList, "CharacterID", "Name"))"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
            <p>Stage</p>
            <select asp-for="Stages" id="stageSelect"
                    class="dropdown"
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.StageList, "StageID", "Name"))"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I followed [This tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/binding-dropdown-list-with-database-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) to get to where I'm at now, and I'm not sure what I could have done differently that's making this not work.

Comment: Looks exactly the same, except for the class property in the <select> element, which in the tutorial they have the value "form-control" instead of "dropdown". Try using the value they have to see if that is changing how the drop down look.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't change anything on the page, thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: That's weird. I did it [here](https://www.bootply.com/ePOrS1BAkw) and the style was applied. Could you please check your html, and verify if there are any style or properties that is overriding the form-control one from bootstrap?

Comment: This will be because of `asp-for="Stages"` - in your case, it looks like `AddGameViewModel.Stages` is of type `List<StageViewModel>`, which is why the `select` element is being rendered with the `multiple` attribute and being displayed as you've shown. If you want to select only one `Stage`, change the property to be `StageViewModel` instead of `List<StageViewModel>`. The same logic applies to to Character, of course.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I actually just tried deleting the text `asp-for="Stages"` and it showed up as a drop down box so I was trying to figure out how that fixed it.                              Edit: I also had to remove the lines `addGameViewModel.Characters = characterList;` and `addGameViewModel.Stages = stageList;` from HomeController.cs. If you want to copy and paste your comment into an answer I'll select it as the correct one.

Comment: Removing `asp-for` isn't the solution here: changing the `AddGameViewModel` as I described is the way to go. You'll run into more problems later otherwise. If you include the `AddGameViewModel` class in your question, I'll write up a more detailed answer, if you like.

Comment: Oh yeah I didn't mean to say that removing `asp-for` was my decided solution, just that I tried removing it and it did what I wanted. My edit after that definitely makes it sound like removing asp-for was my solution. I kept the asp-for, edited `AddGameViewModel` and removed `addGameViewModel.Characters = characterList;` and `addGameViewModel.Stages = stageList;` from HomeController.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both `Characters` and `Stages`, you're using `asp-for`:

```html
<select asp-for="Characters" ...
<select asp-for="Stages" ...
```

Looking at how you configure your `AddGameViewModel`, it seems that it has the following two properties:

```
List<Character> Characters { get; set; }
List<Stage> Stages { get; set; }
```

When the tag-helper processes your `asp-for` expressions, it determines that you want to be able to select *multiple* `Character`s and `Stage`s, simply because the model it's looking at represents a list for each (it ends up adding the `multiple` attribute to the `select` element).

In order to make this work, you can just change the two properties I've mentioned to:

```
Character Character { get; set; }
Stage Stage { get; set; }
```

This will also require you to remove the following (already redundant) lines:

```
addGameViewModel.Characters = characterList;
addGameViewModel.Stages = stageList;
```